# Finding Aes256 keys

Tags: encryption, aes, reverse-engineering

I have a question about aes keys.

I have a binary file which contains an aes256 key (32 bytes) at an unknown offset.
Would it be somehow possible to find this key in the file? Is it somehow possible to tell whether the next 32 bytes would be a valid aes key?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Thanks for all of your answers, 
The key is stored in the file as normal bytes.
I finally managed to create a way to get it.
I basically filter out all strings, which actually made it work.
Thanks again

Comment: Only way to know is to try it as a decryption key.

Comment: Why is the type of this binary file?

Comment: Yep, looking at the format of the file and removing everything that isn't a key could work as well, for a relatively simple file anyway. Similar to creating a statue of an elephant by chipping away everything that is not an elephant :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes and no. AES-256 keys *should* consist of just 32 bytes that are indistinguishable from random. Most files do not consist of just random bytes, so it could be possible t find a sequence that is *most likely* random, and this could be that key you are looking for. However, it might very well be that there are other random sequences in the file, or sequences that look like random but aren't random at all (such as the binary representation of the number Pi).

It may also be that you are unlucky and that the AES key doesn't look all that random. Or that the key is stored in hexadecimals (text) rather than binary byte values. Then there is the issue of finding the exact offset that might be the problem (is that initial byte with value 0x20 indicating the size of the AES key, a space character or part of the key value)?

Most files have a specific format, so you should first have a look at that. Just looking for random sequences may give you both false positives (rather likely) or false negatives (less likely). If you expect 64 bytes of randomness (two keys) then I suggest you search for that first, as it brings down the chance of false positives by a rather large amount.

Answer (score 0):

No - unless you have a way to verify the key against a known plaintext/ciphertext pair - an AES key is not distinguishable from random noise.  Any set of 16, 24 or 32 bytes is a valid AES key.

Comment: Well, possibly the rest of the file is distinguishable from random noise...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah that is actually a good point!  I guess what I'm trying to say is that AES keys themselves have no distinguishable features or sequences.

Comment: Um, I think you get what I was saying, so I'll not go into the fact that you distinguish *between* things. Being random **is** the possible distinguishable feature, together - obviously - with the size of the key. There are (or should be) no distinguishable features other than that, unless they are explicitly created and specific to above file.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah I get what you're saying - I may have made some assumptions about what the OP was asking.  I figured they were asking if there was a structure or format to AES keys - similar to how a bcrypt hash can be represented as a string like `$2y$12$cSIoJ5/cISqEncN3wkV8XeDBu4qkbLXXrCeY.le2soIe4K5UTnAhm` and be easily recognizable.  But I understand the point you are making also.